# How to turn on the alpha component

Tags: meteor, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I am following this [guide](https://github.com/Q42/meteor-gke/blob/master/documentation.md) to create a meteor app on kubernetes with gke.

Right at the beginning i am told to turn on the alpha component:

> Follow the steps in Before You Begin to create a project, enable billing, 
>   and activate the Container Engine and Compute Engine APIs. **Don't**
>   **forget to turn on the alpha component!**

I am not sure how to that, what is the command for it?

When i tried to skip it, i got the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.container) Invalid choice: 'kubectl'.
Usage: gcloud alpha container [optional flags] <group | command>
  group may be           builds | clusters | images | node-pools | operations
  command may be         get-server-config

For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
  gcloud alpha container --help
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands in that tutorial are very out of date. Instead of running `gcloud alpha container kubectl create -f mongo-pod.json`, use the installed version of `kubectl` that comes with gcloud and run `kubectl create -f mongo-pod.json`.

Likewise, when you see `gcloud alpha container replicationcontrollers ...` in the script you should replace it with `kubectl replicationcontrollers ...`.

You may also want to send the maintainer of that repository a pull request to update their documentation and/or scripts.